# Compile or Cross-compile open source driver for Aquaris E4.5 Ubuntu Phone

Tags: drivers, kernel, ubuntu-touch, cross-compilation, aquaris

I am trying to connect an OTG USB-Ethernet adapter on the Aquaris E4.5 running kernel 3.4.67. The adapter is Cable Matters AX88179 which has [open source drivers](http://www.asix.com.tw/download.php?sub=driverdetail&PItemID=131) available for linux.

The installation requires the source files for the device's kernel which however are not on the device. I've tried installing the respective linux-headers but they are not available for the kernel image I have (found through `uname -r`). Installing the source or linux generic headers gives errors as I run out of i-nodes on the phone.

Is there a way of cross-compiling the C drivers for the Aquaris?

Comment: I tried setting up a cross-build environment using the [kernel's source code from github](https://github.com/bq/aquaris-E4.5) but I run into several problems with missing header files (plat, mach, gcc5). Has anyone cross-compiled anything on this thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To cross-compile for Aquaris E4.5 on an x86 Ubuntu host you need the ARM androideabi toolchain. You can install that with:

```
$ sudo apt install gcc-arm-linux-androideabi
```

The Linux kernel source code for Aquaris E4.5 can be found on [BQ's GitHub page](https://github.com/bq/aquaris-E4.5). As documented on BQ's README file, you can build the kernel with:

```
$ ./makeMtk -t krillin n k
```

To cross-compile the AX88179 drivers (I expect the procedure to be similar for other drivers but I haven't tested it on anything but the AX88179 drivers) I modified the drivers' `Makefile` as follows:

```
export ARCH:=arm
export CROSS_COMPILE:=arm-linux-androideabi-
TARGET  = ax88179_178a
OBJS    = ax88179_178a.o
MDIR    = drivers/net/usb
KDIR    = <absolute-path>/aquaris/out/target/product/krillin/obj/KERNEL_OBJ
USBNET  = $(shell find $(KDIR)/include/linux/usb/* -name usbnet.h)

EXTRA_CFLAGS = -DEXPORT_SYMTAB
PWD = $(shell pwd)

obj-m      := $(TARGET).o

default:
    make -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules

$(TARGET).o: $(OBJS)
    $(LD) $(LD_RFLAG) -r -o $@ $(OBJS)

clean:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) clean

.PHONY: modules clean

-include $(KDIR)/Rules.make
```

Make sure to replace the KDIR value with your absolute path to `KERNEL_OBJ` in the `aquaris` directory.

After this you get the cross-compiled kernel object, which you should then 1) transfer and 2) load onto your phone (the following commands should be executed on the phone after the kernel object `ax88179_178a.ko` is transfered):

```
# modprobe usbnet
# insmod ax88179_178a.ko
```

Et voilà! Ethernet OTG worked for me.